# Web server in DMZ needs to write to queue - local or remote?

Tags: wcf, msmq, windows-server-2012

This is on a windows 2012 server

Have a web server A that is in a DMZ, so no domain accounts there.  I want to write to a msmq queue on a server B inside the domain.  Would it be better instead to write to a local private queue on A, and then have something such as a WCF service on B subscribe to the queue on A?

Comment: What are your priorities? Performance, security, etc. The rule is usually "write remote, read local".

Comment: Yes, I agree with "write remote, read local".  However, in this case the "remote" location is behind a firewall.  So instead of poking a hole in the firewall, Id rather write local and read remote.  So the approach I think I need to take is to have something like a service (running behind the firewall), reach out to the queue on the server in the dmz.

Comment: Writing locally means the messages are stored in queues on server A, accessible by any machine that can connect to it. You would need to use proper security to protect the messages. 
Writing remotely means messages only exist transiently in the outgoing queue and on the wire.